# Power BI refresh from BigQuery - Error - Invalid page token, too short

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi

Today multiple Power BI refreshes fails. We use Google BigQuery as a data source.

It returned a error:

```
Data source error:  <ccon>DataSource.Error: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][BigQuery] (100) HTTP Error 400: invalid (Invalid page token, too short.).. </ccon>. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
Cluster URI:  WABI-WEST-EUROPE-B-PRIMARY-redirect.analysis.windows.net
Activity ID:  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Request ID: fff40cfa-894c-4bc7-91e4-33e50130bb1c
Time: 2023-06-08 08:29:06Z
```

The behaviour is quite random because rerunning Power BI refresh often result with same error but not always.

Inside Google BigQuery jobs I do not see any errors.

Do you have some suggestions?

Comment: The error disappears today and all refreshes are working as usually. I was also in contact with Microsoft support but during that time we can not reproduce a error to collect a logs for another investigation. So is seems to be a transient error. Reason is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing the same issue as of this morning.
As a temporary fix I refreshed the data model in PowerBI Desktop and that works without any issues. I only see the issue in app.powerbi.com.